# Chrome Canvas bug on Mac OS X when switching spaces?

Tags: javascript, html, google-chrome, canvas

I have a simple Breakout clone created using the `<canvas>` element and the 2d context.

Whilst playing the game in Google Chrome *(version: 49.0.2623.87 (64-bit))* if I switch spaces within Mac OS X *(version: 10.11.3)* and then switch back to the space which contains Chrome, on occasion, the Chrome canvas renders with a white rectangle covering ~80% of it, this remains even on subsequent full canvas `clearRect()` and redraws. The only guaranteed way (without reloading the document completely) I have found to resolve this issue is to switch to a different tab in chrome then switch back. This issue does not occur in either of the latest versions of Safari or Firefox.

Image prior to switching spaces:
[image: Image prior to switching spaces]

Image after switching spaces with issue:
[image: Image after switching spaces with issue]

I have also recorded a screencast of the issue, Initially the game is paused and I switch to the next space in Mac OS X which has FireFox loaded with the same game, I switch back to the space with Chrome and everything is ok, I play the game for a small time then pause it again and then switch to the next space in Mac OS X which has the game loaded in Firefox and you can see that does not have any issues, then I switch back to the space with Chrome, on switching back the issue presents itself. I then create a new tab in Chrome and switch back to the tab with the breakout game in to clear the issue.

Has anyone ever experienced this before and/or know how to fix it?

Thanks

Comment: I have the same problem in chrome with a Mac while developing a webapp. If I draw the canvas, go to another tab and back to the webapp tab, then the canvas will be cleared and no matter what I try to do, I wont get the canvas redrawn.

Comment: The only hack it worked for me was to remove the non working canvas dynamically, add a new canvas, and redraw it in the window.onfocus event (same chrome version)

Comment: I have the same problem. I've managed to fix it with this way
document.addEventListener("visibilitychange", function() {
  var oldWidth = canvas.width
  canvas.width = oldWidth + 1
  canvas.width = oldWidth
  // redraw canvas content here
});

Answer (score 1, accepted):

This appears to be tracked in https://crbug.com/588434 - it looks like a fix went in and was merged to Chrome 50 and 49 - i.e. it will appear on the next update to Chrome, whether that's the upgrade to 50 or a security push for 49.